# The "3 highs" and "3 lows" when choosing a husband

Tags: culture

Recently I was told about a popular concept among japanese women concerning choice of the future husband. The concept was called '3 高' - three high points, meaning that a good husband should have: 1) high salary; 2) high social status; 3) and be tall.
Later I was told that '3 高' is not valid anymore, as is nowadays replaced by '3 低' - three low points. Could someone please tell what these 3 low points are?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is more of a cultural question than one related to the language.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

「[三低]{さんてい}」 consists of:

1.「[低姿勢]{ていしせい}」(low profile):

We now must keep a low profile to be preferred by Japanese women in 21st century.  We must be polite, non-swaggering and sincere.

2.「[低依存]{ていいぞん}」(low reliance):

We shall not rely on our female partners for all the household chores.

3.「[低]{てい}リスク」(low risk):

We must choose a career that is relatively stable like that of a government employee, teacher, etc.  We must acquire special skills, certifications, etc. that no one can take away from us.

BTW, the 「三高{さんこう}」 mentioned in English by the questioner are 「高収入{こうしゅうにゅう}」、「高学歴{こうがくれき}」 and 「高身長{こうしんちょう}」 in the original Japanese.

Comment: Is there any equivalent concept used by men when choosing a wife? I could imagine several criteria that seem to be important, but I am wondering if there is a commonly used terminology similar to what was discussed above. (I realize this becomes partly a culture question, but since its related to the above topic...)